Video play when div has class active and pause when has class next
Div's with video has 3 other classes - active, prev and next. I want to play a video when the div has class "active". For div's '.item' querySelectorAll doesn't work and querySelector works only on the first div ( play movie but don't pause when the div class changes from active to prev or next).


const slider = document.querySelector(".items");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const clp = document.querySelector(".vd")

let current = 0;
let prev = 2;
let next = 1;

for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener("click", () => i == 0 ? gotoPrev() : gotoNext());
}

const gotoPrev = () => current > 0 ? gotoNum(current - 1) : gotoNum(slides.length - 1);

const gotoNext = () => current < 2 ? gotoNum(current + 1) : gotoNum(0);

const gotoNum = number => {
  current = number;
  prev = current - 1;
  next = current + 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
    slides[i].classList.remove("prev");
    slides[i].classList.remove("next");
  }

  if (next == 3) {
    next = 0;
  }

  if (prev == -1) {
    prev = 2;
  }

  slides[current].classList.add("active");
  slides[prev].classList.add("prev");
  slides[next].classList.add("next");
}

function crnt(){
  if(slider.classList.contains('active')){
    clp.play();
  }
  if(slider.classList.contains('prev') && slider.classList.contains('next')){
    clp.pause();
  }
}
crnt();
 .items {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
}

.items .item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  height: 750px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 105px -35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.item.prev {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.25;
  transform: translate(-125%, -50%);
}

.item.next {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.25;
  transform: translate(25%, -50%);
}

.items .button-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 275px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.button-container .button {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.button-container .button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button-container .button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -99;
}

.button-container .button:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

.button-container .button:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}
div > h2{
   position: absolute;
   color: #f99f00;
   font-size: 8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   rotate: 270deg;
   font-family: 'eurostile',Arial,sans-serif;
   top: 25%;
   left: 60%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.active1{
  width:250px;
  height:750px;
}
<div class="items">
    <div class="item active">
        <video class="vd" src="https://www.oleofarm24.pl/data/include/cms/0cms-podstrony-l/2_film_FORTE_mobilka.mp4?v=1720421734786"
        type="video/mp4" muted loop>
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class=" item next">
        <video class="vd" src="https://www.oleofarm24.pl/data/include/cms/0cms-podstrony-l/1_film_KIDS_mobilka.mp4?v=1720421734787"
        type="video/mp4" muted loop>
           </video>
    </div>
    <div class="item prev">
        <video class="vd" src="https://www.oleofarm24.pl/data/include/cms/0cms-podstrony-l/3_film_K2_mobilka.mp4?v=1720421734786"
       type="video/mp4" muted loop>
          </video>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="button"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></div>
        <div class="button"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/ewm4fzc.css");
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
</style>



Div's with video has 3 other classes - active, prev and next. I want to play a video when the div has the class "active".

the idea in itself is flawed and an XY issue. If you add the class then you still need a setInterval to check if the container has this class. This is resource-wise and speed-wise inefficient. The smarter move would be to dispatch events with the same function that would add those classes to trigger the functionality you want.

Can you explain what are your trying to achieve? I am not able to understand
